# WP_Query class not found

Tags: wp-query, ajax

The idea is simple. I have a drop-down menu generated with get_categories(). This outputs a list of categories in an unordered list, each in it's own li element.
I'm getting the text values of those li elements when a user clicks them, and based on that i want to create a custom wp_query, that returns posts from that category only. To do this, i`m loading the text value of the list element into a JS variable, send it over to a php file for processing. That php file constructs the string like so:

```
$ff_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2&category_name='.$_POST['JSvariable']);
```

… and ideally should execute it, returning the info from the DB. The error i get is:

> "**Fatal error**:  Class 'WP_Query' not found in **C:\xampp\htdocs\suply\wp-content\themes\suply\includes\proc_cat.php** on line **3**"

This is what my 2 files look like:

1) file that sends the ajax request:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#ddmenu li").on('click', function() {
            var cValue = $(this).text();
            $.post("<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/includes/proc_cat.php", {name: cValue}, function(cat){                
                alert(cat);
                $(".browse-big-slider").append(cat);
            });//end of post
        });//end of click
    });//end of ready
</script>
```

2) file that should process the

```
if(isset($_POST)){
        $name = 'posts_per_page=2&category_name='.$_POST['name'];
        $ff_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2&category_name='.$_POST['name']);
      something else, but it won`t reach this part.
}
```

What can i do to make this work? Or as an alternative, how can i create the type of functionality i want? (basically, a different query, generated dynamically, based on a user selection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when calling a theme template directly you only have what's included/defined in the template file, not the whole WordPress environment.

Some people attempt to fix this by adding an include of wp-header or load etc but this is **incredibly damaging**

When doing AJAX requests, **never** call a file in the theme, instead call the WP AJAX APIs.

With the WP AJAX API your file becomes a simple function in `functions.php`.

I strongly suggest you follow the advice of this article:

http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/#js-global

e.g.
PHP:

```
wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) )
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myajax-submit', 'myajax_submit' );

function myajax_submit() {
    // get the submitted parameters
    $postID = $_POST['postID'];

    // generate the response
    $response = json_encode( array( 'success' => true ) );

    // response output
    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo $response;

    // IMPORTANT: don't forget to "exit"
    exit;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery.post(
    // see tip #1 for how we declare global javascript variables
    MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    {
        // here we declare the parameters to send along with the request
        // this means the following action hooks will be fired:
        // wp_ajax_nopriv_myajax-submit and wp_ajax_myajax-submit
        action : 'myajax-submit',

        // other parameters can be added along with "action"
        postID : MyAjax.postID
    },
    function( response ) {
        alert( response );
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for resonding so quickly :) I stumbled upon that article as well, but didn`t understand much, since i`m very new at both WP and AJAX, but i will give it a go, and hopefully come to a result. Just to be on the safe side though, am i on the right track trying to implement this using WP AJAX APIs (or AJAX for that matter)?

Comment: For listing categories in a dropdown menu? Probably not worth bothering with AJAX, if there's a lot of them then there'll be too many to be navigable, so use autocomplete scripts instead

Comment: You didn`t understand what i wanted. My needs are: when a user clicks on an element of the drop down, a custom query is created based on his selection. I can`t have a predetermined list of selectable elements, since that list is dynamically generated when the admin creates his categories.

Comment: Then ignore my comment and pay attention to my answer instead for the correct and reliable usage of AJAX in WordPress

Comment: Hiya, the website you linked to seems to have been removed; do you think you could find a similar article elsewhere or add a description to your article?