# Use jQuery and AJAX to get HTML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery function in my theme that should send an array of filters to a PHP file, which should then return a piece of HTML with the filtered posts (it then replaces the contents of a `<div>` in the page.)

If Wordpress could work with ajax in the "usual" way, I'd do this:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    var args = {};
    args.tipo = 'cultural';
    args.temas = 'colonial';
    $('.cube').click(function()
    {           
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/searcher.php',
                datatype: 'html',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {filters: args}, 
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#grid-search').empty();
                    $('#grid-search').html(data);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
//get all the html for a search in here
//send it back to main page through AJAX
//Have jquery replace the div
$html = "";
$filters = $_POST['filters'];
$taxArgs = array('relation' => 'AND');

if($filters)
{
    foreach ($filters as $key => $filter) 
    {
        array_push($taxArgs, tax_args($filters, $key));
        //the tax_args() function just reads an element in the array to use as WP_Query taxonomy argument
    }
}

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'obra', 
    'tax_query' => $taxArgs,
    'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
{
  //each iteration builds a post to be added to the result
  $loop->the_post();
  $img = get_field('foto_destaque');
  $thumb = $img['sizes']['medium'];

  $html .= '<div class="img_grid">';
  $html .=  '<h1><b>'. the_title() . '</b></h1>';
  $html .=  '<a href="' . the_permalink().'"> <img src="'. $thumb .'"> </a>';
  $html .=  '<div class="social-bar">';
  $html .=      '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/social-bar.png">';
  $html .=  '</div>';
  $html .= '</div>';        
}
echo $html;
```

I googled around for how to do it properly in WP and only came out more confused. I've seen a response [here in Wordpress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67185/wp-query-class-not-found) (this one didn't work for me and I couldn't understand why, I had an error about wrongly hooking, or something like that) and some on external sites. Most dealt with forms and returned JSON data. I need to deal with JS functions and return HTML code. Since Wordpress/AJAX interaction is terribly unintuitive, I didn't manage to understand and adapt the code I saw.

Comment: Start with reading [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: I second @Milo's suggestion, besides when working with WordPress doing it the WordPress-way will keep you saner in the long run.

Comment: I am not developing a plugin. This is just code that my theme needs to use.

Comment: Same, same, but different. Short it doesn't matter.

Comment: That guide uses a plugin as an overall example, but using ajax in plugins or themes is basically the same.